# SQL query help - declaration of variables within a function

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write a SQL function but an having problems with declaring the variables I need for use in the WHERE clause.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getEmployeePolicies(@employeeid smallint)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
DECLARE @empLoc varchar
DECLARE @empBusA varchar
DECLARE @empType varchar
@empLoc = SELECT Location FROM fn_getEmployeeDetails(@employeeid)
@empBusA = SELECT BusinessArea FROM fn_getEmployeeDetails(@employeeid)
@empType = SELECT Type FROM fn_getEmployeeDetails(@employeeid)
RETURN select PolicyId, PolicyGroupBusinessArea.BusinessArea, policysignoff.PolicyGroupLocation.Location, policysignoff.PolicyGroupEmployeeType.EmployeeType
from policysignoff.PolicyGroupPolicy
LEFT JOIN policysignoff.PolicyGroupBusinessArea on policysignoff.PolicyGroupBusinessArea.PolicyGroupId=policysignoff.PolicyGroupPolicy.PolicyGroupId
LEFT JOIN policysignoff.PolicyGroupLocation on policysignoff.PolicyGroupLocation.PolicyGroupId=policysignoff.PolicyGroupPolicy.PolicyGroupId
LEFT JOIN policysignoff.PolicyGroupEmployeeType on policysignoff.PolicyGroupEmployeeType.PolicyGroupId=policysignoff.PolicyGroupPolicy.PolicyGroupId
where BusinessArea = @empBusA
AND EmployeeType = @empType
AND Location = @empLoc
GO
```

The logic I am trying to build in is:

'given an employeeId, return all "applicable" policies'
An "Applicable" policy is one where the Business Area, Location and EmployeeType match that of the user.

I am trying to use another function (fn_getEmployeeDetails) to return the BusArea, Loc & EmpType for the given user.
Then with the results of that (stored as variables) I can run my select statement to return the policies.

The problem i am having is trying to get the variables declared correctly within the function.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your error actually is, I can only say that you're properly not after using varchar as datatype without specifying length.

`DECLARE @empLoc varchar` will declare a varchar with length 1. 
Chances are it should be something like `varchar(255)` or similar.

Second to set variables you'll either need to use SET and use paranthisis for selects or set it into the statement:

`SET @empLoc = (SELECT Location FROM fn_getEmployeeDetails(@employeeid))`
or
`SELECT @empLoc = Location FROM fn_getEmployeeDetails(@employeeid)`

There are subtle differences between these two methods, but for your purpose right now I don't think it's important.

EDIT:
Based on your comment you lack a `BEGIN` after `AS`, and an `END` before `GO`.

Basically - your function syntax is mixing up "inline" table function with "multi-statement" function.
Such a function "template" should look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION <Table_Function_Name, sysname, FunctionName> 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    <@param1, sysname, @p1> <data_type_for_param1, , int>, 
    <@param2, sysname, @p2> <data_type_for_param2, , char>
)
RETURNS 
<@Table_Variable_Name, sysname, @Table_Var> TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    <Column_1, sysname, c1> <Data_Type_For_Column1, , int>, 
    <Column_2, sysname, c2> <Data_Type_For_Column2, , int>
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set
    RETURN 
END
GO
```

*(script taken from sql server management studio)*

Comment: Thanks Allan.
The parenthesis sorted the select statements.
Unfortunately the declaration of the variables still doesn't work even with the length added.
The error I get is:
"incorrect syntax near declare. expecting begin or return"

Comment: I've amended my answer